# Can't change shape drawable's height

Tags: android

The code is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="line">
<stroke android:color="#00000000"/>
<size android:height="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

but no matter what I set ass height what I get is always 1dp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<stroke 
   android:width="10dp" 
   android:color="#000000" />
```

Comment: Yeap this one works! Although I can't understand what was my mistake. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to mentioned height and width both params with size tag.
try the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="line">
<stroke android:color="#00000000"/>
<size android:height="10dp" android:width="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line" 

    android:layout_height="100dp" 
    android:layout_width="100dp">

    <stroke
        android:width="10dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```